# How to combine two resistors in a circuit reduction

Tags: resistors, circuits

I'm new to electrical engineering so I've been watching MIT's Open Course Ware videos on Circuits and Electronics. In one of the lectures, the professor discusses the different methods to use in order to reduce a circuit to a simpler form. One of the methods he describes as the "intuitive" method, where you consolidate components within the circuit intuitively.

Here is an example he gave:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fx8CU5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The problem I'm having is, he states he takes the sum of the two conductances (R2 and R3) and that equals `((R2 * R3) / (R2 + R3))`, how does he get `((R2 * R3) / (R2 + R3))`?

Shouldn't the sum of the two conductances just be `R2 + R3`?

Link to course video where he describes the problem at 31:00: [MIT 6.002 Circuits and Electronics | Lec 2](https://youtu.be/2vHGYdepKLw?t=1896)

Comment: Write out the equations that define the conductances and then simplify.  That is: 1 / ((1 / R2) + (1 / R3))

Comment: These aren't conductances, rather resistances. If they were conductances, then yes G_eq=G1+G2, but since they are resistances then 1/R_eq= 1/R1 + 1/R2.

Comment: Sum of G's = Inverse of sum of inverse R's to get same formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplifying series/parallel resistive circuits you use two formulas.

For N resistors in series,

\$R_T=R_1+R_2+...+R_N\$

and for N resistors in parallel,

\$1/R_T=1/R_1+1/R_2+...+1/R_N\$

or transpose to get:

\$R_T=1/(1/R_1+1/R_2+...+1/R_N)\$

You can solve these circuits by identifying series connected resistors and combining them, then parallel connected resistors and combining them, and repeating until only one resistor is left.  In the simple circuit you provide:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fi2l50.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There are no simple series connected resistors, so check parallel.  R2 and R3 are connected in parallel, so we combine them using the formula:
\$R_{2+3}=1/(1/100\Omega+1/100\Omega)=1/(2/100\Omega)=50\Omega\$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7kfDl.png)</sup>

And now we check for series connections again and see we can combine the remaining two resistors.

\$R_T=R_1+R_{2+3}=150\Omega\$

You can invert the formulas and resistances to figure it out based on conductance, but usually this type of problem is figured out in terms of resistance.

Comment: How does the professor get `(R2 * R3) / (R2 + R3)`? The equation you are using is `1/(1/R2 + 1/R3)`

Comment: Your professor has added a step to produce a common denominator over the resistance formula by multiplying each term by the denominator of the other terms divided by itself(1).  He then simplifies the resulting equation.